# JS Datatable view previous row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Trying to view/select previous row in a Datatable.

In the events defined at the top I have:

```
"click #viewPrevious" : "viewPrevious",
```

So when my viewPrevious button is clicked, the function is called.

my viewPrevious function:

```
this.clearInputOverlay();
var rowData = this.table.row(this.selectedRow-1).data();
for(i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) {
    $('#input' + i).val(rowData[i]);
}
```

This allows me to view the data from the previous row and display it in the overlay pop up where people can edit/scroll through rows. However, to be able to continually click this button so that you can view previous rows until there are no more - I need to actually mark the new row selected so when we come back to this function later, `this.selectedRow` will be updated and you can keep viewing previous nodes.

So now I'm trying to add some additions to the function:

```
var rowIndex = this.table.row(this.selectedRow).index();
```

to get the current row, so I can deselect this row and select the previous row using `.addClass('selected')` method.

However, I can't figure out how to get/modify one specific row in the DataTable:
The following are attempts I tried but didn't work:

```
//attempt 1
this.table.row(this.selectedRow).addClass('selected');

//attempt 2
$('#dataTable tbody tr').row(this.selectedRow).addClass('selected')

//attempt 3
this.table.row(rowIndex-1).addClass('selected');

//attempt 4
$('dataTable tbody tr').row(rowIndex).addClass('selected');
```

Syntax error or conceptual misunderstanding?! Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it using JQuery .prev()

var current = $('.selected'); 
current.prev().addClass('selected');